# mod_rewrite rule to send css|js to dynamic link

Tags: css, apache, mod-rewrite, gzip, wamp

I want to send all requests for a file ending with css or js to a script
this is the rule i have and it is not working

```
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ /gzip.php=$0 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css)$ /gzip.php=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks this works, but now when I gzip the css my cssimages are broken even though I use absolute paths... :(